# send html email from java(spring, use MimeMessageHelper)

Tags: java, spring

I use MimeMessageHelper.
I try send this code:

```
 public void sendingMessage(String toAddress, List<String> list) throws MessagingException {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage =  javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

    helper.setTo(toAddress);

 for (String properties : list) {

        String[] split = properties.split("_");
        String name = split[0];

        String quantity = split[1];
        String photo = split[2];

      //FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File(imagePath+photo));
      //helper.addAttachment("ThankYou.jpg", file);
        helper.setText(name+" - "+quantity+"pieces.");
        helper.setText(quantity);
        helper.setSentDate(new Date());
        helper.setText("<img src='+imagePath+photo+'>"+"---"+name+"****"+quantity, true);

    }
```

I recieve `List<String> list`, as:

```
[glenDev_5_whisky/glenDeveron.jpg, Tomintoul_3_whisky/Tomintoul.jpg, Alfa Suf_5_whisky/OldPulteney.jpg]
```

I have two problems:

1. I don't recieve image if I use

   ```
   helper.setText("<img src='+imagePath+photo+'>"+"---"+name+"****"+quantity, true);
   ```

But if I use this code:

```
FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File(imagePath+photo));
          helper.addAttachment("ThankYouForTheOrder.jpg", file);
```

I receive all images from `List<String>` list

2. I can't understand how I can will send several image+name+ some text, that will describe  this image.
   For example: One image, his name and describe, another image his name and describe... etc.

Comment: Is `imagePath` an absolute URL or relative?

Comment: imagePath: 
`D:/stadyIdea/siteVersion02/src/main/resources/static/`

Comment: I saw such example:`helper.setText("<html><body><img src='cid:identifier1234'></body></html>", true);`, but what is `'cid:identifier1234'` I can't understand

Comment: You need to have absolute web URLs for any image you need to show in email.

Comment: Ok, I remade code:
`helper.setText("<img src='http://localhost:8080/whisky/OldPulteney.jpg'>"+"---"+name+"****"+quantity, true);`
I have received
`<img scr="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/aCD5gc7U0KymSqs1HxDsLKU2gz1O8w_bZxm7SVDak9fHzRQuAeLwvKx8U40MuEF-_MHL_0BYqDc5WkOenrF5WtAj3w=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost:8080/whisky/OldPulteney.jpg" class="CToWUd"> `

Comment: Think yourself why a localhost URL wouldn't work.